# Select images from variable

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to develop memory game. I got an array with images.

```
var img = [
    "img/icon1.png",
    "img/icon2.png",
    "img/icon3.png",
    "img/icon4.png",
    "img/icon5.png",
    "img/icon6.png",
    "img/icon7.png",
    "img/icon8.png",
    "img/icon9.png",
    "img/icon10.png",
    "img/icon11.png",
    "img/icon12.png",
    "img/icon13.png",
    "img/icon14.png",
    "img/icon15.png",
    ]

var c_array = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15];
var c_length = c_array.length;
var $card = $('.card');    
$card.each(function() {
   var r_id = Math.floor(Math.random() * (c_length - 1));
   var temp = c_array[r_id];
   c_array[r_id] = c_array[c_length - 1];
   c_array[c_length - 1] = temp;    
   c_length--; });
```

I wanna select some images from this array in order to construct a specific board.

How can i select only 8 images from this array?

EDIT: 
I wanna take out first 8 icons, i think its gona be easier than random icons, where you need to make shuffling function.Then i wanna have array with 8 pairs, ( can it be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] ? but how to double it so there will be 16 items in array not 8) then shuffle array and put it on board

Comment: Please be a lot more specific about what your problem and expected results are. Take some time to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Be more specific.  First 8 items? Last 8 items? Random 8 items? And regarding pairs, Ordered pairs? (1&2, 3&4, etc.)  Random Pairs?

Comment: I wanna take out first 8 icons, i think its gona be easier than random icons, where you need to make shuffling function.Then i wanna have array with 8 pairs, ( can it be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] ? but how to double it so there will be 16 items in array not 8)  then shuffle array and put it on board.